# how can I split more than 2 columns with fix limit and group the column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table as Images.

```
TableName    ColumnName     RecordId        Caption                  ImageType      ROTId   DetailRecordId  GroupCount
Table1      ItemPhoto_bin   11480170        caption                  ItemPhoto      1041383 11480170            1
Table1      ItemPhoto_bin   11480171        test photo               ItemPhoto      1041383 11480171            1
Table1      ItemPhoto_bin   11480172        description              ItemPhoto      1041383 11480172            1
Table2      PAUTDPhoto_bin  1462$1463$1464  test$test1$testing photo PAUTPhotos     1041383 11480170            3
Table2      PAUTDPhoto_bin  1465$1466       test$55                  PAUTPhotos     1041383 11480172            2
```

I want to split the string which contains '$' in RecordId and Caption.
My output select query will do the following actions,

1. Need to split the RecordId and Caption columns value which contains '$'. (only if the value contains more than 2 split values)
2. After splitting the text we need to segregate the RecordId and Caption with new rows and provide the same row details individually.

My output should be,

```
TableName    ColumnName     RecordId    Caption          ImageType      ROTId     DetailRecordId    GroupCount
Table1      ItemPhoto_bin   11480170    caption          ItemPhoto      1041383   11480170            1
Table1      ItemPhoto_bin   11480171    test photo       ItemPhoto      1041383   11480171            1
Table1      ItemPhoto_bin   11480172    description      ItemPhoto      1041383   11480172            1
Table2      PAUTDPhoto_bin  1462$1463   test$test1       PAUTPhotos     1041383   11480170            3
Table2      PAUTDPhoto_bin  1464        testing photo    PAUTPhotos     1041383   11480170            3
Table2      PAUTDPhoto_bin  1465$1466   test$55          PAUTPhotos     1041383   11480172            2
```

I've tried with cross apply STRING_SPLIT(RecordId, '$') but it will be splitting all values into new rows.

```
values
11480170
11480171
11480172
1462
1463
1464
1465
1466
```

like above. I want to split the values only columns (RecordId and Caption) that have more than 2 $ values.
Ex. if RecordId has **1462$1463$1464$1455** value and Caption **test$test1$testing photo$detail photo** has then the output should create 2 rows with value

```
RecordId        Caption
1462$1463      test$test1
1464$1455      testing photo$detail photo
```

Comment: I would suggest that you fix your design here, in truth. *Don't* store delimited data in your database in the first place.

Comment: @Larnu Correcting myself here, I'm not storing delimited data in the database. But I'm getting this value from another query.  So I want to perform this action on that query result.

Comment: Can you share this *another query* so you may get help to fix this issue from the beginning?

Comment: Then don't aggregate your strings before you need to consume them as a non-aggregated value, @Pankaj .